# how to one click logout in odoo 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, odoo-9

I want to create a one click logout for odoo , so i create odoo theme and add an icon for logout , when you click on the icon , the user logged out . so i have a piece of code in .xml

```
<xpath expr="//ul[@class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right oe_user_menu_placeholder']" position="inside">
    <li><a href="#" class="logout" title="Logout"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i></a></li>
</xpath>
```

and in java script code .js

```
var UserMenu = require('web.UserMenu');
var user_menu=new UserMenu(self);
$(document).ready(function () {
$( ".logout").click(function() {
  $( ".logout").click(function() {
         user_menu.on_menu_logout();
   });
  });
});
```

so i call the **on_menu_logout()** function of **web** module and the **on_menu_logout()** also called but in side the function  **this.trigger('user_logout');** function did not call . so if you have any idea please share with me to solve this .

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this would be to call the http controller that controls the logout.

The route of the controller is "/web/session/logout"

When calling this controller, it will instantly logout the user and end his session.

You can call this controller like this in your javascript:

For this, a lower-level API exists on on Session() objects (usually available through openerp.session): the rpc method.

This method simply takes an absolute path (the absolute URL of the JSON route to call) and a mapping of attributes to values (passed as keyword arguments to the Python method). This function fetches the return value of the Python methods, converted to JSON.

For instance, to call the resequence of the DataSet() controller:

```
var session = require('web.session');
session.rpc('/web/session/logout', {}).then(function (result) {
console.log('Logout Successful')
}, function () {
// an error occured during during call
});
```

Comment: thanx@Bhavya for reply , but that code will be generate an error ,     **Odoo Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 646, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 683, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 295, in _call_function
    raise werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequest(msg % params)
BadRequest: 400: Bad Request**

Comment: Function declared as capable of handling request of type 'http' but called with a request of type 'json' , means we should be call the controller with request of type 'http' , so suggest me how to call the funcation in request of type 'http' .

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer to solve this , we don't need any extra javascript to solve this just follow this code and add an attribute **t-attf-href** in to ***a*** tag, so follow this code i.e

```
<li><a t-attf-href="/web/session/logout?redirect=/web/login" title="Logout"><i class="fa fa-sign-out iconsize"></i></a></li>
```

Thanks